# Compile PureScript function to uncurried JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, currying, purescript

The following PureScript function:

```
add :: Number -> Number -> Number
add a b = a + b
```

... compiles to JavaScript as follows:

```
var add = function (a) {
    return function (b) {
        return a + b;
    };
};
```

I would like to call this function on iOS using the JavaScriptCore framework and this makes it more complicated than it needs to be. Is there a way to compile to uncurried functions?

Comment: `const uncurry = f => (...args) => args.reduce((f, arg) => f(arg), f);` assuming you know the correct number/order of args, `const uadd = uncurry(add); uadd(2, 3); // 5` (this doesn't improve readability if that is your goal)

Comment: Use a tuple instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at the functions in [`Data.Function.Uncurried`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-functions/3.0.0/docs/Data.Function.Uncurried) - the `mkFnN` helpers will allow you to define JS multi-argument functions from the PS-curried versions.

The tradeoff is you won't be able to call these functions the normal way in PS, you'll have to use the corresponding `runFnN` also. Not really an issue if this module is only exposing an FFI interface though. :)